# Scraping from specific div without attribute where tags can have the same name

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from wowhead. The issue is that the span classes are the same for 2 different types of data (Sell for: and Buy for:).

The division under which the spans are have no class and just the stings I wrote in the brackets.

I've tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import lxml
session = requests.session()
url1 = 'https://classicdb.ch/?item=4291'
response = session.get(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

x=(soup.find('table', attrs={'class': "infobox"}))
y=x.find('td')
y=y.find('ul')

sell_silver = soup.select_one('div:contains("Sells for:") .moneysilver').text
buy_silver = y.select_one('div:contains("Buy for:") .moneysilver').text
print(sell_silver)
print(buy_silver)
```

but then I only get the first span.

The relevant HTML after i get the table looks like this

```html
<div>
 Buy for:
 <span class="moneysilver">5</span>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
 Sells for:
 <span class="moneysilver">1</span> <span class="moneycopper">25</span>
</div>
```

....

The end result should allow me to sort the data into

> Buy_silver=5
>
> Sell_silver=1

edit to clarify question and shoutout @QHarr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BS4 4.7.1+ you can use `:contains` to target by `Buy for` or `Sells for`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://classicdb.ch/?item=4291')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
buy_silver, sell_silver = soup.select_one('li:contains("Buy for") .moneysilver').text , soup.select_one('li:contains("Sells for") .moneysilver').text
```

Comment: Hey, i seem to get pretty close with your sugestion. When i copy past your answer i get the same but if i apply it to my code both buys and sell become 5.

the complete code looks like this, without imported libs
session = requests.session()
url1 = 'https://classicdb.ch/?item=4291'
response = session.get(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

x=(soup.find('table', attrs={'class': "infobox"}))
y=x.find('td')
y=y.find('ul')
sell_silver = y.select_one('div:contains("Sells for:") .moneysilver')
buy_silver = y.select_one('div:contains("Buy for:") .moneysilver')

Comment: Is it the code or the html? I applied some changes to make the html complete. Is there an url to use?

Comment: Yes,

classicdb.ch/?item=4291

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I cant upvote yet otherwise i would.

Why does it make a difference it you look for the li tag instead of div?

Comment: if you use div it select for a parent div that actually houses both divs containing sell and buy. Using li takes you to the level where adding the child class returns 1 at a time only based on :contains

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the buy and sell quotes are always in the same order and distance from each other, you can try to use this:

```
metal = """
<li>
<div>
    Buyfor:
    <span class="moneysilver">5</span>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
    Sells for:
    <span class="moneysilver">1</span> <span class="moneycopper">25</span>
</div>
</li>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(metal, 'lxml')
silver=soup.find_all('div')

print("buy silver =",silver[0].find("span", class_="moneysilver").text)
print("sell silver =",silver[1].find("span", class_="moneysilver").text)
```

Output:

> buy silver = 5
>
> sell silver = 1